# The cart is not updating any item when add to button is called

Tags: php, html, jquery, shopping-cart

I have an issue with my cart. Basically when a user clicks add to cart it is supposed to add that item to cart for view. Currently I am getting failed to add item from JavaScript side. When debugging I think I am not passing all parameters to the servers side and need some help. On the server side I can see response from the browser when inspecting using network and 200 status. But on the file itself I get success: error, invalid response.

// html code

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-right">
    <a href="#" class="btn border">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary"></i>
        <span class="badge">0</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pb-1">
    <div class="card product-item border-0 mb-4" id="product_item">
        <div class="card-header product-img position-relative overflow-hidden bg-transparent border p-0">
            <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="img/product-1.jpg" alt="" id="product_img">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body border-left border-right text-center p-0 pt-4 pb-3">
            <h6 class="text-truncate mb-3" id="product_name">Colorful Stylish Shirt 0</h6>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <h6>R120.00</h6>
                <h6 class="text-muted ml-2" id="price">
                    <del>R120.00</del>
                </h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between bg-light border">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0 view-details-btn" id="cart-0">
                <i class="fas fa-eye text-primary mr-1"></i>View Detail
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm text-dark p-0 add-to-cart-btn" id="cart-1">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart text-primary mr-1"></i>Add To Cart
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

// jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-to-cart-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var product_item = $("#product-item").val();
    var price = $("#price").val();
    var product_img = $("#product_img").val();
    var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
    // Send an AJAX request to update the cart in the database
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update-cart.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { id: id, product_item:product_item, price:price, product_img:product_img, quantity:quantity},
        success: function(response) {
            // Handle the response from the server
            if (response.success) {
                // Update the cart badge count
                var cartBadge = $('.fa-shopping-cart + .badge');
                var cartCount = parseInt(cartBadge.text());
                cartBadge.text(cartCount + 1);
            } else {
                // Handle the error scenario
                alert('Failed to add item to the cart. Please try again.');
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

// php code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'error.log');


// Check if the AJAX parameter is present
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') 
{
    // Proceed with the AJAX request

    // Database connection details
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'ecommerce_store';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    // Retrieve the product information from the AJAX request
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' 
        && isset($_POST['id']) 
        && isset($_POST['quantity'])) 
    {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

        // Print the received data for debugging
        echo 'Received Data: ';
        echo 'id: ' . $id . ', ';
        echo 'quantity: ' . $quantity;
        echo 'price'.$price;
        echo 'product_name'.$product_name;

        try {
            // Connect to the database
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // Update the cart item with the new quantity or perform other operations
            // Example: Update the quantity in the cart table
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE cart SET quantity = :quantity WHERE id = :itemId");
            $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
            $stmt->bindParam(':itemId', $id);
            $stmt->execute();

            // Return a success response
            $response = ['success' => true];
            echo json_encode($response);
            exit; // Stop executing further code
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Return an error response
            $response = ['success' => false, 'error' => $e->getMessage()];
            echo json_encode($response);
            exit; // Stop executing further code
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Invalid request']);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Invalid request']);
}
?>
```

Comment: You might want to tweak your two error messages to be slightly different, so you know if the first `if` block is returning false, or if the second one is.

Comment: I found the element with the id of `product_item` but that does not have a value `<div class="card product-item border-0 mb-4" id="product_item">`

Comment: Ditto the others

Comment: @RiggsFolly correct spot, i am now busy trying to amend this code, issue seem to be on my js why server is unable to read all these values being sent

Comment: _"issue seem to be on my js why server is unable to read all these values being sent"_ - because div elements don't have any value you could read with `.val()` - you would need to get the `.text()` of those (and possibly also trim it.) Or - put that info into custom data attributes instead; or use an actual form with hidden fields (then you can simply serialize that as a whole, and don't need to grab values one by one.)